# Onkeyup to fire a get request after only a few charcters

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using Onkeyup to fire when a user inputs a certain ID into the search box. One problem I am trying to fix is having the function run only after 4 or more characters are in the submission box. For example, the ID number 0949 is fired when the user types out each digit, returning a GET request error each time when it should only fire at the end of the 4 digit submission. Here is a screenshot from the console log: [image]

Ive tried including a .length to my onkeyup function as well as a fail catch to try but nothing works and it still fires after every single input. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
const getAssetInfo = (assetTag, index) => {
// get the table row that this input is in
$.get("http://localhost:3000/assets/" + assetTag , (data) => {
  // find the `.description` element and set it's value 
  if (data){
    $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${index}`).val(data.serial_no);
    $(`#description${index}`).val(data.description);
    $(`#cost${index}`).val(data.cost);
    $(`#po_no${index}`).val(data.po_no);
  }
  
  console.log(data);

})

.fail(() => {
    // alert("DONE");
    // console.log(index);
    $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${index}`).val("");
    $(`#description${index}`).val("");
    $(`#cost${index}`).val("");
    $(`#po_no${index}`).val("");
}); };
```

```
$('document').ready(() => {


    // Handler to Add New Asset
    const table = $("#formTable tbody");
    let count = 1;

    $('#add').click(() => {
        
        const newRow = `
                        
                    <tr index="${count}">
                    <form>
                    <td><input class="asset-tag" id='asset_tag_no${count}' type='text' 
                    onkeyup = "getAssetInfo(this.value,${count})";
                    bottom required /></td> 
                    
                    <td><input  class="serial-no" id='manufacturer_serial_no${count}' type='text' bottom required readonly/></td>
                    <td><textarea class="description" id='description${count}' type='text' bottom required readonly description></textarea></td>
                    <td><input id='cost${count}' type='value' bottom require readonly/></td>
                    <td><input id='po_no${count}' type='text' bottom require readonly/></td>
                    <td><textarea id='remarks${count}' type='text' bottom remarks></textarea></td>
                    <td><button type="button" index="${count}" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
        `;

        table.append(newRow);
        // Handler to Remove New Asset
        $('.btn-remove').click(function(){
            let index = $(this).attr('index');
            $(`tr[index='${index}'`).remove();
        });

        count++;
    });

What is the most optimal way to ensure that only 4 or more digits can be entered into the search box, before it sends a GET request?
```

Comment: You're calling getAssetInfo on every keyup. Maybe create another function for the keyup to analyse the input before calling getAssetInfo

Comment: @Pellay how would I go about doing that, im not the strongest at functions. And would I need the length character as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to wrap your getAssetInfo function with an if statement checking the amount of characters in the searchbar. Try rewriting the getAssetInfo function like this:

```
const getAssetInfo = (assetTag, index) => {
  if (assetTag.length >= 4){
    // get the table row that this input is in
    $.get("http://localhost:3000/assets/" + assetTag , (data) => {
      // find the `.description` element and set it's value 
      if (data){
        $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${index}`).val(data.serial_no);
        $(`#description${index}`).val(data.description);
        $(`#cost${index}`).val(data.cost);
        $(`#po_no${index}`).val(data.po_no);
      }
      
      console.log(data);

    })

    .fail(() => {
        // alert("DONE");
        // console.log(index);
        $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${index}`).val("");
        $(`#description${index}`).val("");
        $(`#cost${index}`).val("");
        $(`#po_no${index}`).val("");
    });
  } else {
    console.log('not enough characters to call API endpoint');
  }
};
```

In this if statement, I'm checking if the search bar has 4 or more characters before making the API call.

Comment: Although this will work, it's not good practice to mix your logic and api functions like this.